# Snakemake, pandas, and NCBI: how do I combine a pandas dataframe with the remote NCBI search?

Tags: pandas, snakemake

I'm still pretty new to Snakemake, and I've been having trouble with a rule I'm trying to write.

I've been trying to combine using snakemake.remote.NCBI with accessing a pandas dataframe and using a wildcard, but I can't seem to make it work.

I have a tsv file called genomes.tsv with several columns, where each row is one species. One is "id" and has the genbank id for the species's genomes. Another "species" has a short string unique for each species. In my Snakefile, genomes.tsv is imported as genomes, with only the id and species column, then species is set as genomes index and dropped from genome.

I want to use the values in "species" as values for the wildcard {species} in my workflow, and I want my rule to use snakemake.remote.NCBI to download each species's genome sequence in fasta format and then output it to a file "{species}_gen.fa"

```
from snakemake.remote.NCBI import RemoteProvider as NCBIRemoteProvider
import pandas as pd

configfile: "config.yaml"

NCBI = NCBIRemoteProvider(email=config["email"]) # email required by NCBI to prevent abuse

genomes = pd.read_table(config["genomes"], usecols=["species","id"]).set_index("species")

SPECIES = genomes.index.values.tolist()

rule all:
    input: expand("{species}_gen.fasta",species=SPECIES)

rule download_and_count:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: NCBI.remote(str(genomes[str(wildcards.species)]) + ".fasta", db="nuccore")
    output:
        "{species}_gen.fasta"
    shell:
        "{input} > {output}"
```

Currently, trying to run my code results in a key error, but it says that the key is a value from species, so it should be able to get the corresponding genbank id from genomes.

EDIT: here is the error

```
InputFunctionException in line 18 of /home/sjenkins/work/olflo/Snakefile:
KeyError: 'cappil'
Wildcards:
species=cappil
```

cappil is a valid value for {species}, and it should be usable as an index, I think. Here are the first few rows of genomes, for reference:

```
species id  accession   name    assembly
cappil  8252558 GCA_004027915.1 Capromys_pilorides_(Desmarest's_hutia)  CapPil_v1_BIUU
cavape  1067048 GCA_000688575.1 Cavia_aperea_(Brazilian_guinea_pig) CavAp1.0
cavpor  175118  GCA_000151735.1 Cavia_porcellus_(domestic_guinea_pig)   Cavpor3.0
```

Update:

I tried changing the the input line to:

```
lambda wildcards: NCBI.remote(str(genomes[genomes['species'] == wildcards.species].iloc[0]['id']) + ".fasta", db="nuccore")
```

but that gives me the error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/**init**.py", line 547, in snakemake
    export_cwl=export_cwl)
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 421, in execute
    dag.init()
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 122, in init
    job = self.update([job], progress=progress)
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 603, in update
    progress=progress)
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 666, in update_
    progress=progress)
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 603, in update
    progress=progress)
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 655, in update_
    missing_input = job.missing_input
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/jobs.py", line 398, in missing_input
    for f in self.input
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/jobs.py", line 399, in 
    if not f.exists and not f in self.subworkflow_input)
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 208, in exists
    return self.exists_remote
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 119, in wrapper
    v = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 258, in exists_remote
    return self.remote_object.exists()
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/remote/NCBI.py", line 72, in exists
    likely_request_options = self._ncbi.guess_db_options_for_extension(self.file_ext, db=self.db, rettype=self.rettype, retmode=self.retmode)
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/remote/NCBI.py", line 110, in file_ext
    accession, version, file_ext = self._ncbi.parse_accession_str(self.local_file())
  File "/home/sjenkins/miniconda3/envs/olflo/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/remote/NCBI.py", line 366, in parse_accession_str
    assert file_ext, "file_ext must be defined: {}.{}.. Possible values include: {}".format(accession,version,", ".join(list(self.valid_extensions)))
AssertionError: file_ext must be defined: ... Possible values include: est, ssexemplar, gb.xml, docset, fasta.xml, fasta, fasta_cds_na, abstract, txt, gp, medline, chr, flt, homologene, alignmentscores, gbwithparts, seqid, fasta_cds_aa, gpc, uilist, uilist.xml, rsr, xml, gb, gene_table, gss, ft, gp.xml, acc, asn1, gbc

Comment: Please provide the exact error that Snakemake produces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that the reason that I was getting `AssertionError: file_ext must be defined:` is that NCBIRemoteProvider can't recognize the file extension if the file name that its given doesn't have a valid Genbank accession number. I was giving it file names with genbank ids, so it returned that error.

Also, it seems like the whole genome sequences don't have an accession number that returns all the sequences. Instead there's an accession number for the wgs report and then accession numbers for each scaffold. I decided to try downloading the genomes I need manually instead of trying to download all the scaffolds and then combine them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have:

```
genomes = pd.read_table(config["genomes"], usecols=["species","id"])

SPECIES = list(genomes['species'])
```

and then access the ID of a given species with:

```
lambda wildcards: str(genomes[genomes['species'] == wildcards.species].iloc[0]['id'])
```

Comment: I tried using the top code lines, and then modifying download_and_count's input to ```lambda wildcards: NCBI.remote(str(genomes[genomes['species'] == wildcards.species].iloc[0]['id']) + ".fasta", db="nuccore")``` but that gave me an Assertion Error message:
AssertionError: file_ext must be defined: ..<file_ext>.